# Find a metric on $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that the sequence of natural numbers is Cauchy.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Find a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ that is equivalent to the usual metric and has the property that the sequence $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I know that if I have two metric spaces $(M, \rho)$ and $(N, \sigma)$ and a 1-1 function $f : M \to N$ such that $f$ is a homeomorphism of $M$ onto $f(M)$, then the topologies generated by the two metrics $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are equal. So if $\tau$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}$, then I need to find a metric $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which has the property that the sequence $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, and such that there is a homeomorphism of $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of $(\mathbb{R}, \tau)$ onto $(f(\mathbb{R}), \rho)$.

One of the hints I have is to find a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ onto a bounded interval, but I'm not yet sure how to proceed.

Any ideas or answers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: $d(x,y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y|$.

Comment: @Crostul Is this equivalent to the usual metric? From the integral representation it's clear that your $d(x, y)\leq\left|x-y\right|$, what about the other direction?

Comment: $d_1=\dfrac{d}{1+d}$

Comment: @learnmore Can you explain why the metric $d_1$ has the property that the sequence $(n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy? I can't seem to get it to work.